# How to implements these mime types in F5 - irules

Tags: mime-types, f5, irule

```
<LocationMatch "\.(?i:pps)$">
             ForceType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
             Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</LocationMatch>
```

ForceType application/vnd.openxmlformats–officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
                Header set Content-Disposition attachment

Comment: this is fairly simple to do, but I'm not an apache user, so will need a little help to provide an answer. Is the locationMatch matching inbound request on the location header, or the URI? And I'm assuming the ForceType is to set the Content-Type header? Finally, is this for response to client?

Comment: Yes, it's Content-Type. Also, yes it's for response to client

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which direction you are wanting these applied, and I'm not an apache user, but the header actions are simple. Pick your request/response event, match the appropriate string and the header actions are:

```
HTTP::header replace Content-Type application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
HTTP::header insert Content-Disposition attachment
```